# Changing layer colours across multiple Photoshop documents

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, actions

I'm designing an app, and when I designed the screens, over 40 of them, I did it in the clients colours.

We've now settled on a new colour scheme, and I need to replace old colours with new ones. Is there a way I can assign one colour to change to another across multiple documents?

I don't want to have to spend a few minutes per screen changing each layer manually if I can avoid it. There has to be a way I can create an action or something to speed it all up.

Comment: i would be curious to see if there is a solution to that. good question!

Answer (score 1):

Other than paying for a plugin, and since you've already created each separate layer in each separate screen with no 'connection' to a smart object or each other, it's not currently possible.

My suggestion, since you would have to go through each screen separately now anyways, would be to:

1. Add a smart object layer filled with color and mask it to the object you want colored(alt/option-click between the layers in question with the colored smart object on top).
2. Copy(alt/option drag) that smart-object-color layer above any other objects that need that color, mask again, etc. Do this with as many different colors as you need.
3. Then, if you need to change colors again in the future you can double-click one of the smart-object-color layers, fill with the new color, and all corresponding smart objects will update, changing the color wherever that smart-object-color layer has been copied.

Again, doesn't alleviate having to go through all your screens this time, but might save you some time in the future. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awesome Plugin :)
http://www.codeadventure.com/

And if you want to use this in one document just use the new canvas feature in CC 2015.

Comment: Please do not only give a link. Is that plugin free or not. Is this ment as spam? Explain how this plugin and/or the canvas feature could solve the question.

Comment: I`m recommending this plugin because I´m using it since the Beta and it fits the requirements of Richard. The product page explains very well the purpose and how it works - why should I quote everything?

The plugin is not free, but it´s worth the money because it´s a real time-saver. You can use it with multiple documents - but if you want "multiple" version in one document, you can use the new canvas feature (that was just a tip - but not needed for the plugin)